# Data is not filling in name field through angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, http, get

Hello Everyone I am getting data through Angular ajax call 
here is the call

```
 $scope.EditOperator = function ($event) {
    $event.stopPropagation();
    var ID = $scope.idSelectedOperator;
    $http.post('/api/privilege/editopap/' + $scope.idSelectedOperator)
        .success(function (data, status) {
            $scope.Operator=data;
            $scope.Operator.Name = data.name;
            alert($scope.Operator.Name)
            $scope.Operator.Password = $scope.EditOperator.name;
            $scope.Operator.Email = data.email;
            $scope.$applyAsync();
            toastr.success("Update Successfully");

        }).error(function () {
            toastr.error("Something went wrong");

        });
};
```

I am getting data as i wanted but when i am trying to assign data in

```
 $scope.Operator.Name = data.name;
```

then it is showing undefined in console.
here the data i am getting is

```
**email:"gaurav1verve@gmail.com"
id:0
name:"Gaurav"
password:"tyh"**
```

and $scope.Operator is an object which contain the three fields

```
 $scope.Operator = {
    Password: '',
    Email: '',

    Name: ''
};
```

Comment: just define data = $scope above $http.post and pass data parameter in $http.post like this $http.post('/api/privilege/editopap/' + $scope.idSelectedOperator, data)..... by doing this way you can access $scope in the success or error callbacks of $http.post

Comment: please mention your answer